# I need all even days in a month and all odd days in a month in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

```
SELECT
    "user_id",
    cast("created_date" as date),
    EXTRACT(DAY FROM  cast("created_date"as timestamp))
FROM
    "loan"
WHERE
    date_trunc('month', cast("created_date" as date)) = date_trunc('month', cast(now() as date))
    AND MOD(EXTRACT(DAY FROM cast("created_date" as timestamp)),2) = 0
GROUP BY
    cast("created_date" as date),
    "user_id"
```

this is giving error as :-

> ERROR: function mod(double precision, integer) does not exist Hint: No
> function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to
> add explicit type casts. Position: 451

Answer (score 0):

you get that error because output of `extract` is double precision, and `mod()` function expects two parameter with the same data type.

so if you cast your extract output you won't get that error message :

```
AND MOD(EXTRACT(DAY FROM cast("created_date" as timestamp))::int,2) = 0
```

However I don't think that query works, here is what I think you are trying to do:

```
SELECT
    "user_id",
    cast("created_date" as date),
    count(*) filter (where MOD(EXTRACT(DAY FROM cast("created_date" as timestamp))::int,2) = 0 )) EvenDaysNo , 
    count(*) filter (where MOD(EXTRACT(DAY FROM cast("created_date" as timestamp))::int,2) <> 0 )) OddDaysNo
FROM "loan"
WHERE cast("created_date" as date)) = cast(now() as date))
GROUP BY
    cast("created_date" as date),"user_id"
```